# Is it possible to bindkey Shift+Enter in zsh?

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I'm starting to use zsh on macOS Sierra. I would like to have the following key mappings:

- Enter => accept-line
- Shift-Enter => accept-and-hold

However, I can't seem to differentiate between the two. I'm only able to get Enter, and Esc-Enter, but not Shift-Enter:

```
bindkey "^M"   accept-line     # Enter
bindkey "^[^M" accept-and-hold # Esc-Enter
bindkey "????" accept-and-hold # Shift-Enter
```

Is it possible to detect and handle Shift-Enter?

Answer (score 15):

`zsh` (as well as other shells) do not act on key bindings but rather on key sequences received from the terminal. Converting key presses and combinations into key sequences is the responsibility of the terminal. You can retrieve the key sequence for a key combination by pressing <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> followed by the key combination, e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

By default <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (as well as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>) all generate the identical key sequence `^M` (at least in most common terminal emulators).

Fortunately, some terminal emulators allow to configure the key sequences sent. For example *iTerm2* allows you to set customized key bindings that send escape sequences (in *Profile > Keys*), you should be able to define a sequence for <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> there, e.g. `[[SE` and can then make the appropriate settings in `zsh`: `bindkey '^[[[SE' 'accept-and-hold'`. (Unfortunately I do not have access to a Mac at the moment, so I could not test this).

Comment: Your answer saved me. I'm using mac and its default bash __zsh__ indeed provides options to define key sequences: Preferences > Profiles > [+] button.

Answer (score 0):

This might answer your problem (can't put it into comment, don't have 50 rep). You might try `# showkey --scancodes` which gives you key codes and take a look into the manual-pages e.g. `man zshzle` and search for "code". I have tried to map the shift key without success. Might be it's not possible. Also have a look into `bindkey -l` wich gives you the keymaps and `bindkey -M emacs` for emacs keymap

Comment: `showkey` does not appear to be available on macOS.

Comment: You might try http://macbiblioblog.blogspot.de/2014/12/key-codes-for-function-and-special-keys.html?m=1 or google for mac key codes